# ошибка mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property

Tags: java, hibernate

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FLOWER")
@NamedQuery(name = "getFlowers", query = "SELECT c from Flower c")
@XmlRootElement(name = "FLOWER")
public class Flower implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_cust")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_cust", sequenceName = "seq_cust", allocationSize = 1)

@Column(name = "FLOWER_ID")
private Long flowerId;

@Column(name = "FLOWER_NAME")
private String flowerName;

@Column(name = "FLOWER_COST")
private float flowerCost;

@Column(name = "FLOWER_IN_STOCK")
private int flowerInStock;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="FLOWER")
private Set<Position> position;

public Flower() {

}

public Flower(String flowerName, float flowerCost, int flowerInStock) {
    this.flowerName = flowerName;
    this.flowerCost = flowerCost;
    this.flowerInStock = flowerInStock;
}

public Long getFlowerId() {
    return flowerId;
}
@XmlElement
public void setFlowerId(Long flowerId) {
    this.flowerId = flowerId;
}

public String getFlowerName() {
    return flowerName;
}
@XmlElement
public void setFlowerName(String flowerName) {
    this.flowerName = flowerName;
}

public float getFlowerCost() {
    return flowerCost;
}
@XmlElement
public void setFlowerCost(float flowerCost) {
    this.flowerCost = flowerCost;
}

public int getFlowerInStock() {
    return flowerInStock;
}
@XmlElement
public void setFlowerInStock(int flowerInStock) {
    this.flowerInStock = flowerInStock;
}

public static long getSerialversionuid() {
    return serialVersionUID;
}
@XmlElement
public Set<Position> getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public void setPosition(Set<Position> position) {
    this.position = position;
}


}
```

второй класс

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "POSITION")

@XmlRootElement(name = "POSITION")

public class Position implements Serializable{


private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq_cust")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "seq_cust", sequenceName = "seq_cust", allocationSize = 1)

@Column(name = "POSITION_ID")
private Long positionId;

@Column(name = "POSITION_QUANTITY")
private int positionQuantity;

@Column(name = "POSITION_COST")
private float positionCost;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="FLOWER_ID")
private Flower flower;

public Position() {

}

public Position(int positionQuantity) {
    this.positionQuantity = positionQuantity;
    this.positionCost = positionQuantity*flower.getFlowerCost();
}

public Long getPositionId() {
    return positionId;
}
@XmlElement
public void setPositionId(Long positionId) {
    this.positionId = positionId;
}

public int getPositionQuantity() {
    return positionQuantity;
}
@XmlElement
public void setPositionQuantity(int positionQuantity) {
    this.positionQuantity = positionQuantity;
}

public float getPositionCost() {
    return positionCost;
}
@XmlElement
public void setPositionCost(float positionCost) {
    this.positionCost = positionCost;
}

public Flower getFlower() {
    return flower;
}
@XmlElement
public void setFlower(Flower flower) {
    this.flower = flower;
}

public static long getSerialversionuid() {
    return serialVersionUID;
}



}
```

Comment: `@OneToMany(mappedBy="FLOWER")` => `@OneToMany(mappedBy="flower")`?

Answer (score 2):

правильный ответ дал [сергей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/192547/sergey)

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="FLOWER") => @OneToMany(mappedBy="flower")?
```